# Getting a div contents, using it to apply a class to a matching link

Tags: jquery

I have a div which displays the category number of a single post. I want to grab this category number, find the sub-nav item which matches that number (e.g. li.cat-item-**11**) and apply another class to that list item.

So far I've tried the following, but not much luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getCatNum = $(".project-category").html();
  if ( $(".sub-nav li").hasClass("cat-item-"+getCatNum) ) {
    $(".sub-nav li a").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Any thoughts? Putting **getCatNum** in a var works and displays in console outside the if statement, but not so much luck within it.

Thanks!

**EDIT** -

The HTML:

```
<div class="project-category">
    <?php
        $categories = get_the_category();
        echo $categories[0]->cat_ID;
    ?>
</div>
```

Just grabs the first cat (each post only ever has 1 cat assigned to it). Works OK. I can see the number being outputted.

The **nav** is just a simple one, the code looks like:

```
<nav class="sub-nav">
<ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="#">Fitout</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="#">Hospitality</a></li>
    etc...
<ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you show me the html of the div, and the list

Comment: The code you say is "*The HTML*" is actually PHP; they're rather different. PHP is executed server-side, and is irrelevant to jQuery. What's the actual HTML?

Comment: Thanks David, I'm aware of that. Apologies, I just posted that to show you the number would be dynamic. The HTML outputted is simply: <div class="project-category">11</div> - obviously with that 11 changing depending on which post you're on. Anyway, your example below worked - thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, albeit in the absence of any HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // retrieving the element(s),
  // getting the text from the first element returned,
  // removing leading and trailing white-space from the text:
  var getCatNum = $(".project-category").text().trim();

  // finding the <li> element with the class of '.cat-item-<number>',
  // adding the 'active' class-name:
  $('.sub-nav li.cat-item-' + getCatNum).addClass('active');
});
```